# How to create flyway history for exiting database

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

With my Spring Boot app, I have a database that is already set up but the flyway history table is empty. I would like to run flyway to generate the history table from the migration files.
When I run `flyway:migrate` it does not understand that my database credentials are in application.yml so I had to use a config file as below:

Approach1:

```
mvn -D flyway.configFiles=flyway.config -D flyway.baselineVersion=14 -D flyway.locations=classpath:db.development flyway:baseline
```

No error but it does not generate migration history.
Approach2:

```
mvn -D flyway.configFiles=flyway.config -D flywaytarget=14 -D flyway.skipExecutingMigrations=true -D flyway.locations=classpath:db.development flyway:migrate
```

Gives me an error:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unknown configuration property: flyway.skipExecutingMigrations
```

Any idea how to achieve my goal?